# Prevent calling actual function when using mock.MagicMock

Tags: python, unit-testing, magicmock

I have a model:

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
   def abc(self):
      #some logic here
      return something
```

Say, I have another function which uses this:

```
def filter_graded(evaluations):
    return filter(lambda x: x.is_completely_graded(), evaluations)
```

Now when I am writing test for `filter_graded` method, I mock `is_completely_graded` to return true/false for some instances. Instead of respecting the mock, the test calls actual `is_completely_graded`. How can I solve this?

My test looks like:

```
def test_filter_graded(self):
    eval1 = G(Evaluation)
    eval2 = G(Evaluation)
    eval1.is_completely_graded = mock.MagicMock(return_value=True)
    eval2.is_completely_graded = mock.MagicMock(return_value=False)
    filter_graded(Evaluation.objects.all())
    self.assertEqual(len(result), 1)
```

Comment: first edit of the day...dat too 17sec late!! :\

Comment: Nowhere in your test are you actually replacing real objects with mocks. You are passing in `Evaluation.objects.all()`, `eval1` and `eval2` are *entirely unused*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing in mocked objects. You are passing in real data:

```
filter_graded(Evaluation.objects.all())
```

Nowhere did you mock out `Evaluation` or `Evaluation.objects` or `Evaluation.objects.all()`.

If all your code does is look for objects with a `is_completely_graded` method, just pass in mocks as the sequence, no need to any ORM queries:

```
def test_filter_graded(self):
    eval1 = mock.MagicMock()
    eval2 = mock.MagicMock
    eval1.is_completely_graded.return_value = True
    eval2.is_completely_graded.return_value = False
    filter_graded([eval1, eval2])
    self.assertEqual(len(result), 1)
```